# output html with echo

Tags: javascript, php, html, echo

i am echoing html with php echo

for example :

```
echo "<span onClick='popUpWin('add_page.php?id=".$row[Id]."', 'standard', '1000', '600',30,150)'><img src='images/editbtn.png' class='ddpngfix'></span>";
```

it is displaying data as it should be, my problem is when i click on image it is not calling function popUpWin, it is present on the same page, and when i checked in firebug inspect element it is showing span element totally broken, please check below image

[image]

i know quotes are making problem , How to solve this ?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://phppot.com/php/php-escape-sequences/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `"` for `onclick` and escape it like below:

```
echo "<span onclick=\"popUpWin('add_page.php?id=".$row['Id']."', 'standard', 1000, 600 ,30,150)\"><img src='images/editbtn.png' class='ddpngfix'></span>";
```

Comment: Can you please copy what it's generating.

Answer (score 4):

Escape the `'`s properly -

```
echo "<span onClick=\"popUpWin('add_page.php?id=".$row['Id']."', 'standard', 1000, 600 ,30,150)\"><img src='images/editbtn.png' class='ddpngfix'></span>";
```

No need for `'`s around numbers.

Comment: i tried this but same issue happening, its breaking span element

Comment: Can you add what it is generating?

Comment: firebug showing span elemnt like this :

<span onclick="popUpWin(\" add_page.php?id="6\'," \'standard\',="" 1000,="" 600="" ,30,150)'=""><img src="images/editbtn.png" class="ddpngfix"></span>